# Golang defer fails at times

Tags: go, mutex

I am working on a application with multiple routines. The processor receives an ID (string) and performs some operations. The IDs might be duplicated and I don't want multiple routines to process an ID when another routine is processing it.

I use a sync mutex map for it.

```
type cache struct{
   sync.Mutex
   ids map[string]struct{}
}

func(c *cache) addIfNotPresent(string)bool{
   c.Lock()
   defer c.Unlock()
   if _, ok := c.ids[id]; ok{
       return false
   }
   c.ids[id] = struct{}{}
   return true
}
func(c *cache) delete(string){
   c.Lock()
   defer c.Unlock()
   delete(c.ids, id)
}
```

My processor has an instance of this map. Now my process looks something like this

```
func process(string){
   ok := cache.addIfNotPresent(id)
   if !ok{
      return
   }
   defer cache.delete(id)

   ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)
   defer cancel()
   err := doOne(ctx)
   if err {
      return err
   }
   ...
   return nil
}
```

Using defer so the id gets removed regardless of what happens in processor.

Sometimes (not always) the value does not gets evicted from the map. From the logs/metrics I am certain it was not the error case but the process function was complete and the key was not evicted from the map.

Is there any behavior of mutex or defer I am missing here ?

Comment: As a minimum you should post `addIfNotPresent()` and `delete()` implementations.

Comment: Code looks ok. Are you sure you posted the actual code? arg names are missing, which makes me think maybe more is missing from what we see here.

Comment: I didn't copy paste. But I am sure this is exactly what I have.

Comment: Evidence suggests otherwise. defer() does not fail.

Comment: I edited a bit. The `doOne` function takes in a context. I pass a context with timeout and defering the cancel. Does it make any difference ?

Comment: If this is the real code, then it looks ok. So you're either dealing with multiple copies of that cache, or there's something wrong with the way you check the cache. Did you lock when you looked at the cache?

Comment: I only call the methods on the cache. And both the methods lock the underlying map before making any modifications.

Comment: `defer` does not fail. There's obviously a logic error or incorrect assumption somewhere in your code, but you need to carefully log what you're doing to figure out what that is. Since this is concurrent code, always test with the race detector as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Sometimes (not always) the value does not gets evicted from the map.

How and when are you checking that?

The code for the function you pasted is actually removing the key when finished, but after that execution finishes there might be another goroutine processing (thus adding) the same key again.

Comment: It's a POC system and it's easy to track ids with help of logs/metrics. I have a metric/log after checking `ok` in `process` function. That metric has been getting a hit for about a day in regular intervals now (the interval is same as the id being passed into the function). That with other metrics I can see the only possibility being that the key is not evicted.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see this code causing your metrics function (executed after checking the `ok` in `process`) to see the value in the map is the following:

1. thread1 adds the value to the map and starts processing it. It yields the CPU.
2. thread2 goes into the `process` function, calls `addIfNotPresent` and gets `false`. It yields the CPU before going into `if !ok {`.
3. thread1 gets the CPU, finishes its work, removes the value from the map and exits.
4. thread3 gets the value, checks the map, sees the value is not there anymore, starts processing it. It yields the CPU.
5. thread2 gets the CPU, checks the `ok` and sees it's `false`. At this point it hits your metrics function. Your metrics functions checks the map and sees the value there. Confusion ensues.

A way to verify this is to check the map after the processing is done. If my hypothesis is right you will not see any values still lingering there. If I'm wrong and the values are really not evicted correctly you will still see them there.